# mtext: smaller labels description when layout is used

Tags: r, plot, label, axis-labels, par

Using mtext for the label description does something different than using xlab. How can I make the mtext labels be always the same size as it would be when using xlab (without defining always the cex argument). In the minimal example below cex=cex.lab=1 for both figures. However the size is different.

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,2), ncol=1))
op<-par(mar=c(4,4,2,1))
plot(1:10, xlab="", ylab="", main="This is my title")
mtext("this is the x-axis", side=1, line=2.75, cex=1)
mtext("this is the y-axis", side=2, line=2.5, cex=1)
plot(1:10,  xlab="this is smaller", ylab="this is smaller", main="This is my title", cex.lab=1)
par(op)
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just use either `xlab` or `mtext` for both plots?

Comment: Or use `title(xlab="this is the x-axis", ylab="this is the y-axis")` rather than `mtext`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When layout is used, the meaning of `cex=1` in `plot` is different, but I would not have expected that difference to extend to mtext since its activities are outside the individual plotting regions. You can reverse the default reduction in "effective"-`cex` inside `plot` by inverting the expected factor of 2/3:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,2), ncol=1))
op<-par(mar=c(4,4,2,1))
plot(1:10, xlab="", ylab="", main="This is my title")
mtext("this is the x-axis", side=1, line=2.75, cex=1)
mtext("this is the y-axis", side=2, line=2.5, cex=1)
plot(1:10,  xlab="this is _not_ smaller", 
            ylab="this is _not_ smaller, either", 
            main="This is my title", 
            cex.lab=3/2)
par(op)
```

Further reading:

```
 ?par  # scroll down to mfcol, mfrow
```

Comment: finally chased this issue down, highly frustrating, especially when you query cex in debugging mode and it always shows 1. anyway, according to `mfrow`, `cex.lab=3/2` should be `cex.lab=1/0.83` if there are 2 rows as in your example and `cex.lab=1/0.66` for three or more rows. or more completely, `cex.lab = par('cex.lab') * 1/0.66`

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that you can use `title` instead of `mtext`.

```
title(ylab = "this is the y-axis", line = 3.5, . . . )
```

I had the same problem with font scaling, this way it should work without having to know the scaling factor in advance.